# Explanation for Big-O notation comparison in different complexity class

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

Why Big-O notation can not compare algorithms in the same complexity class. Please explain, I can not find any detailed explanation.

Comment: If all you know is that `f(n) = O(n²)` and `g(n) = O(n²)`, that doesn't tell you which is bigger, `f(n)` or `g(n)`, does it?

Comment: Can  u pls explain a bit more.

Comment: To compare the algos in same complexity class, you need to know the **exact** complexity, i.e., all the _constants_ associated with it. Without that, comparison would be meaningless!

Answer (score 1):

So, `O(n^2)` says that this algorithm requires **less or equal** number of operations to perform. So, when you have algorithm `A` which requires `f(n) = 1000n^2 + 2000n + 3000` operations and algorithm `B` which requires `g(n) = n^2 + 10^20` operations. They're both `O(n^2)`

For small `n` the first algorithm will perform better than the second one. And for big `n`s second algorithm looks better since it has `1 * n^2`, but first has `1000 * n^2`.

Also, `h(n) = n` is also `O(n^2)` and `k(n) = 5` is `O(n^2)`. So, I can say that `k(n)` is better than `h(n)` because I know how these functions look like.

Consider the case when I don't know how functions `k(n)` and `h(n)` look like. The only thing I'm given is `k(n) ~ O(n^2), h(n) ~ O(n^2)`. Can I say which function is better? No.

### Summary

You can't say which function is better because Big O notation stays for **less or equal**. And following is true

```
O(1) is O(n^2)
O(n) is O(n^2)
```

### How to compare functions?

There is Big Omega notation which stays for **greater or equal**, for example `f(n) = n^2 + n + 1`, this function is `Omega(n^2)` and `Omega(n)` and `Omega(1)`. When function has complexity **equal** to some asymptotic, Big Theta is used, so for `f(n)` described above we can say that:

```
f(n) is O(n^3)
f(n) is O(n^2)
f(n) is Omega(n^2)
f(n) is Omega(n)
f(n) is Theta(n^2) // this is only one way we can describe f(n) using theta notation
```

So, to compare asymptotics of functions you need to use **Theta** instead of Big O or Omega.